# Pin Data is very slow at iphone 5

Tags: ios, iphone, performance, parse-platform

When i try to use the ParseObject to store the local data, i find that the     performance is very bad, when i execute below codes at IOS 5, will take about 1 - 2 secs for every loop. But seems that the performance is ok at emulator and iphone 5s.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    PFObject *pfObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"TestStore"];

    pfObj[@"TestStore_ID"] = userId;

    pfObj[@"TestStore_URL"] = avatarUrl;

    [pfObj pinWithName:@"TestStore"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `pinWithName:` method is synchronous and pinning executes SQLite statements under the hood, which can be quite slow. You should try using `pinInBackgroundWithName:` to execute this outside of the main thread.

Comment: but seems that take 1 -2 secs is not normal.

Comment: Did you try `pinInBackgroundWithName:`?

Comment: i tried it, but actually this don't solve the real problem. for that callback still need take 1 -2 secs.